# Indent a package listitem

Tags: lists, indentation, moderncv

I'm new to latex and I understand how to indent lists, but what if they are lists items that are derived from a package. In this case, I really like the `moderncv` package. Here is a working example.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}   
\firstname{Joe}
\familyname{Blow}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Profile}
\cvline{Wet-Lab}{\Large Protein expression and purification}
\cvlistitem{Novel cloning strategies}
\cvlistitem{Novel Pufication strategies}
\cvlistitem{Cell culture and maintenance}
\end{document}
```

I need the `\cvlistitem` indented slightly more than the package gives. Any advice?

Comment: Why do use the `moderncv` package? Does not a normal `enumerate` or `itemize` list suffice, which can be used (probably) in `moderncv` anyway?

Comment: Yea I could do that, but the modern cv has preformatted bullets and indentations that mesh very well with the "look" of the CV

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can adjust the way the item label is set. The macro responsible for this is `\listitemsymbol`, and it needs to be done *before* setting the [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) theme:

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\renewcommand*{\listitemsymbol}{\hspace{2em}\labelitemi~}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}   
\firstname{Joe}
\familyname{Blow}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Profile}
\cvline{Wet-Lab}{\Large Protein expression and purification}
\cvlistitem{Novel cloning strategies}
\cvlistitem{Novel Pufication strategies}
\cvlistitem{Cell culture and maintenance}
\end{document}
```